# Simple operator+ problem eluding me

Tags: c++, math, operator-overloading

I'm trying to add two lists of `uint8_t` as though the list were individual integers, and I'm getting some weird values:

`0x1000 + 0x100 + 0x10 -> 0x1210 ?????`

Code is as follows:

```
// values 0x123456 stored as: {12, 34, 56}
integer operator+(integer rhs){
    // internal list called 'value'
    std::list <uint8_t> top = value, bottom = rhs.value;
    if (value.size() < rhs.value.size())
        top.swap(bottom);
    top.push_front(0);                           // extra byte for carrying over
    while (bottom.size() + 1 < top.size())       // match up the byte sizes, other than the carry over
        bottom.push_front(0);
    bool carry = false, next_carry = false;
    for(std::list <uint8_t>::reverse_iterator i = top.rbegin(), j = bottom.rbegin(); j != bottom.rend(); i++, j++){
        next_carry = (((uint8_t) (*i + *j + carry)) <= std::min(*i, *j));
        *i += *j + carry;
        carry = next_carry;
    }
    if (carry)
        *top.begin() = 1;
return integer(top);
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next_carry = ((*i + *j + carry) > 255);` is the correct answer, due to the extra 1, since `*i + *j + carry` can equal the minimum `std::min(*i, *j)`

Comment: +1, just came to the same conclusion. Stricken the use of `std::min` from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what happens when adding two zero digits and there was no carry. `*i + *j + carry == 0`, which is `<= than min(*i, *j)`. Thus you're generating a carry out of thin air.

If you know you're only working with bytes, you can store `*i + *j + carry` in an `int` and then carry is just `sum / 256`.

Answer (score 3):

In your example (`0x100 + 0x10`), you begins with `carry = false`, `*top.rbegin() = 0`, and `*bottom.rbegin() = 0`. When we drop into the loop we see the following test:

```
next_carry = (((uint8_t) (*i + *j + carry)) <= std::min(*i, *j));
// given *i == 0, *j == 0, and carry == false
// this will evaluate to TRUE
```

Since `next_carry` rolls around to the next addition you end up with `carry = true`, when it should be `false`. <strike>Switch the conditional to `< std::min(*i, *j)`.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Let `maxval` be the maximal value of `uint8_t`.
Determine the existence of `next_carry` as follows:

```
next_carry = false;
if( *i == maxval && ( *j > 0 || carry ) ) // excluding *i + carry > maxval case in next if
        next_carry = true;
    else
        if( *i + carry > maxval - *j ) ///  equal to *i + *j + carry > maxval
             next_carry = true;
```